# Migration from File Api to Storage Access Framework (SAF) in Android

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider, storage-access-framework

Due to Android 11 and scoped storage I have to start work with Storage Access Framework (SAF), but I have lot of source code that works with `File API`. **Question 1**: Do I have to rewrite everything to work with `DocumentFile`?

Pseudo use case:
User creates and picks own directory and system returns `Uri`:

```
//Start pick a directory
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)   
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)

...

onActivityResult {
    //check requestCode + resultCode
    ...
    //get Uri
    val selectedDir = data.getData();
    if (selectedDir == null) {
        return;
    }
    //take persist permission for later use
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(selectedDir, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
}
```

Now I have `Uri` of folder selected by user with read/write persistable permissions.

From [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#media-direct-file-native)

> To help your app work more smoothly with third-party media libraries, Android 11 allows you to use APIs other than the MediaStore API to access media files from shared storage using direct file paths. These APIs include the following:
> The File API.
> Native libraries, such as fopen().

**Question 2**: well, how can I use `File API`, when I have a `Uri` from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`?

**Question 3**: does this mean I have to duplicate all the code to work up to Android 9 (or 10 with `requestLegacyExternalStorage`) with the `File API` and from Android 11+ with the `SAF` and `Uri`?

Goal is: keep the code with the `File API`, but get read/write permissions to the user selected directory.

**UPDATE**
After the huge testing `DocumentFile` is not applicable in practice. Maybe only for a few files.
`DocumentFile` creates unnecessarily complicated source code and it's very sloooow [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42186820/4244605).
For example creating of 1000 directories during via `File API` ~350ms and via `DocumentFile` ~2300ms. Delete and check if file exist are always very slowly.

From [Scoped Storage Recap](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/mwaqn1/scoped_storage_recap/gvh8w2g?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

> Awesome! It would be really great to have some kind of support library or Androidx lib for file handling.

and answer from Google developer is:

> We're exploring this option as an experiment, stay tuned

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` That makes no sense for ACTION_GET_DOCUMENT_TREE. Better remove.

Comment: `I need:

Create a file if it does not exist. With File API:` No. Use SAF for that. What is the pronblem?

Comment: `Write to file. With File API:` Of course not. If you have an uri for the file then open an output stream for the uri and write to the stream.

Comment: `Get Uri of parent with child. With File API:` One will not try to get a parent to begin with.

Comment: `Goal is: keep the code with the File API,` Wrong goal. Use SAF.

Answer (score 1):

Note that *startActivityForResult()* is deprecated. Instead *registerForActivityResult()* shall be used. Unfortunately I have not find any usable Java example for this mechanism, yet. Even Google's example code is still using the deprecated function. I would be glad for any hint.

PS: There is also some *ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()* function that might be helpful, but I also could not find an example how to use it.