# Why does DocumentFile.getName take a relatively long time?

Tags: storage-access-framework

I have seen [posts describing DocumentFile.listFiles() takes a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186820/documentfile-is-very-slow). In my case, it is fairly fast but operations on the retrieved instances of DocumentFile take a long time.

```
DocumentFile[] aFiles = dfDir.listFiles(); //Takes 100 ms with a list of 250 files

//The following takes 5,000ms
for (DocumentFile df : aFiles) {
   boolean bFoo = df.isDirectory(); //takes about 10ms
   String sName = df.getName(); //takes about 10ms
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: The Q/A you posted a link to answers this exact question. [DocumentFile is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186820/documentfile-is-very-slow) – Specifically, "`getName()` invokes `ContentResolver#query()` under the hood ... [this] performs hundreds of queries, which is very inefficient"

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked it. I have linked the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `getName()` invokes `ContentResolver#query()` under the hood ... [this] performs hundreds of queries, which is very inefficient."

From an answer to [the duplicate question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186820/why-is-documentfile-so-slow-and-what-should-i-use-instead).